Replacement derailleur for Schwinn
I got a Target-only Schwinn bike (made by Pacific), and while it's overall a surprisingly good bike, the front derailleur is not ideal. Given that it's a department store Schwinn, it's not made of the best components. The rear is a Shimano, but the front is a no-name. The bike shop near me was able to adjust the front one just enough to use all three front gears, but even after precise adjustment, the derailleur can only barely make all three.
I'd like to replace the front derailleur with a Shimano one so that I don't have to worry about shifting anymore. This is the bike in question: https://www.target.com/p/schwinn-women-39-s-circuit-700c-28-34-hybrid-bike-gray-purple/-/A-80371741. Do you-all have any recommendations for a possible Shimano replacement/substitution for it? I am a complete novice to this.

Do you know what the existing derailleur is?

@DavidW The derailleur has no markings whatsoever, but would you like a picture? If so, what angles would you like?

From the linked site, the front derailleur is a

Bottom entry (where the cable approaches from)
Triple    (three chainrings)
Band-on clamp - so it has to match the size of the bike's frame tube here.

Those should be the only specs you need to match.  Colour doesn't matter functionally, and you could spend a lot or a little on a replacement.
The downside is that the bike still has stamped steel chainrings and a budget plasticky shifter on the left hand, both of which inhibit smooth shifting.   How far down the slippery slope of replacements you want to go is your choice.
Also, consider that front shifting is always harsher than rear shifting because the chain is under tension, whereas the rear derailleur is working with a slack chain.
As long as your front shifter is working, I'd leave well-enough alone and just try to be in the right range before you hit a climb.   When I'm riding, I rarely change chainring unless there's a hill or a long slog headwind.

Thank you, someone who knows what they're talking about! My local bike shop told me the no-name derailleur that comes with the bike was mass-produced to be the wrong size, so that's why I'm replacing it with a proper Shimano. They install/adjust derailleurs for $10, so no problem for me. Now... I will measure the frame tube size, but I am confused as to what "bottom entry" means. (1/2)

https://www.amazon.com/Bicycle-Derailleur-FD-TY300-Tourney-Mountain/dp/B0CSJDZ4ZT, take a look at this. It's a clamp-style derailleur for three gears in the front. Should I buy an up-swing or down-swing, based on what you said (that it's "bottom-entry")? Again, I will measure the tube circumference. (2/2)

@SebastianPojman-Malo bottom entry just means the inner cable comes up from below, as opposed to top entry where the cable comes down from above.  Some MTBs have top entry because of dirt.   In your link, this image shows it better.   https://m.media-amazon.com/images/I/81IJrKYXNQL.AC_SL1500.jpg

I measured the circumference to be 100mm (so exactly 31.8mm), and I'm going to have the bike shop install my new Shimano tomorrow. Already you can see a MASSIVE difference in build quality between the Shimano I just bought and the one that came with the bike.
